# Recorrer array JSON desde PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

```
JSON:

    {

    "_labels": {
        "a": "DOLARTODAY",
        "a1": "DOLAR CUCUTA",
        "b": "IMPLICITO",
        "c": "DICOM",
        "d": "DOLAR BITCOIN",
        "e": "DIPRO"
    },
    "_timestamp": {
        "epoch": "1520611865",
        "fecha": "Marzo 9, 2018 12:11 PM",
        "fecha_corta": "Mar 9, 2018",
        "fecha_corta2": "Mar 2018",
        "fecha_nice": "Marzo 9, 2018",
        "dia": "Viernes",
        "dia_corta": "Vie"
    },
    "USD": {
        "transferencia": 215778.05,
        "transfer_cucuta": 215778.05,
        "efectivo": 22327.24,
        "efectivo_real": 232758.62,
        "efectivo_cucuta": 232758.62,
        "promedio": 215778.05,
        "promedio_real": 39807.50,
        "cencoex": 10.00,
        "sicad1": 236044.85,
        "sicad2": 39807.50,
        "bitcoin_ref": 236044.85,
        "localbitcoin_ref": 240165.62,
        "dolartoday": 215778.05
    },
    "EUR": {
        "transferencia": 265389.74,
        "transfer_cucuta": 265389.74,
        "efectivo": 27504.93,
        "efectivo_real": 286730.69,
        "efectivo_cucuta": 286730.69,
        "promedio": 265389.74,
        "promedio_real": 49038.86,
        "cencoex": 12.32,
        "sicad1": 290783.65,
        "sicad2": 49038.86,
        "dolartoday": 265389.74
    },
    "COL": {
        "efectivo": 0.0116,
        "transfer": 0.0116,
        "compra": 0.0116,
        "venta": 0.01
    },
    "GOLD": {
        "rate": 1322.51
    },
    "USDVEF": {
        "rate": 10.2087
    },
    "USDCOL": {
        "setfxsell": 2700.00,
        "setfxbuy": 2650.00,
        "rate": 3447.00,
        "ratecash": 2700.00,
        "ratetrm": 2700.00,
        "trmfactor": 0.2,
        "trmfactorcash": 0.06
    },
    "EURUSD": {
        "rate": 1.23188
    },
    "BCV": {
        "fecha": "1520308800",
        "fecha_nice": "Marzo 6, 2018",
        "liquidez": "210.858.494.946",
        "reservas": "9.444.000"
    },
    "MISC": {
        "petroleo": "59,28",
        "reservas": "9,4"
        }
    }
```

Quiero recorrer el array de JSON a traves de PHP.
Este es mi Codigo

```
<?
$url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json";
//$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($xml);

var_dump($obj);

$obj = array();            
foreach ($obj as $respuesta){
    $obj[$respuesta->USD]["promedio"] = $respuesta['resultado'] -> array(); 
}

$datos['USD-Promedio'] = $respuesta;
echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me da NULL

Comment: ¿El resultado que te gustaría obtener es `{"USD-Promedio": 215778.05}`?

Comment: Si, ese el resultado que quisiera obtener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144868/recorrer-array-json-desde-php?noredirect=1#comment271514_144868), te diría que no necesitas iterar el objeto, solo necesitas acceder al valor que buscas.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);

$datos['USD-Promedio'] = $obj->USD->promedio;
echo json_encode($datos);
```

Comment: Gracias ya me funciono

Comment: Si soy nueva, vale perfecto ya lo lei... Ahora otra consulta, quiero multiplicar ese resultado por una variable, pero he probado y no me funciona!

Comment: @AndreaValentina, te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta describiendo exactamente el problema, el código que has intentado y el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta línea

```
$obj = json_decode($xml);
```

Por esto

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Te da null cuando dumpeas pk estas pasandole a json_decode una variable que no existe.

Un consejo: En la línea antes de tu foreach no inicialices la variable **$obj** porque no entrará nunca a tu ciclo, intenta crear otra variable y los cambios los reflejas en esa nueva.

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo NULL

Comment: haz un echo $json despues de cargarlo desde la url

Comment: No me habia percatado que habia dejado el $obj = json_decode($xml), pero al cambiarlo por $obj = json_decode($json), y al no inicializarle la variable $obj me da este error: no se puede usar el objeto de tipo stdClass como matriz en la linea "$obj[$respuesta->USD]["promedio"] = $respuesta['resultado'] -> array();"

Comment: Eso te sucede porque json_decode($json) devuelve un objeto por tanto no puedes acceder a sus propiedades como si fuera un array. Si quieres hacerlo de esa manera tienes que pasarle un segundo parámetro y asignarle true, es decir json_decode($json, true).